# HTACCESS - ErrorDocument + RewriteRule = Infinte Loop

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, errordocument

I got an issue with `ErrorDocument` and `RewriteRule`. In simple words, here is what I have:

```
 1. ErrorDocument 404 http://www.MYSITE.com/Cust404.html

 2. RewriteEngine On
    #/Some very needed custom rewrite conditions
    . 
    .
    .
    RewriteRule ^.* - [R=404,L]
```

The result of this is infinite loop (obviously). However, I dont know how to solve this. Anybody got any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Can you try `ErrorDocument 404 http://www.MYSITE.com/Cust404.html` below the `RewriteRule ^.* - [R=404,L]`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ [R=404,L]
```